# collect data from child components in a react form with variable number of children

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Given that React hooks cannot be called in a loop, I'm struggling on how to collect data in a form composed of a variable number of child components.
Let's say I have the following code with hard-coded two children and I want to convert this code to use a loop enabling variable number of child components:

```
const ref0 = useRef();
const ref1 = useRef();

const handler = (e) => {
  alert( [ref0.current.value , ref1.current.value] );
}

const Child = ( {nameRef} ) => {
  return
   <input type="text" ref={nameRef} />
}

<form onSubmit={handler}>
    <Child nameRef={ref0} />
    <Child nameRef={ref1} />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The problem is that I cannot call `useRef()` in a loop to have an array of references to child inputs from which I want to collect data.

I tried looking up similar problems but couldn't find anything near what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `ref`, you can use `state`:

```
const Child = ( props ) => {
    const { value, onChange } = props;
    return <input
        type="text"
        value={ value }
        onChange={ event => {
            onChange( event.target.value );
        }}
    />;
}

function MyComp() {

    const [ formState, setFormState ] = React.useState({
        child1: '',
        child2: '',
    });

    const handleChange = key => value => {
        setFormState( prevState => {
            return {
                ...prevState,
                [key]: value,
            };
        })
    }

    return <form>{
        Object.keys( formState ).map( key => {
            return <Child
                key={ key }
                value={ formState[ key ] }
                onChange={ handleChange( key ) }
            />
        })
    }</form>
}
```

If need to use `useRef()` for some reason, you can still put the whole array
into the ref:

```
const refs = React.useRef([ ... ]);
```